# How to disable app install Mini-infobar in chrome android

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, google-chrome-app, chromium

I've added a Native app install banner as specified by https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native.

My requirement is that a dialog with install button should be shown on all browsers and on clicking on install, Native app install banner should be shown on chrome and on other browsers it should use the firebase dynamic link.

I have mimicked the app install dialog consisting App logo, title , description and an install button as shown.

[image: App Install Banner]

On all the browsers except for chrome, This dialog will be shown instantly and the install button links to firebase dynamic link which opens the app if installed else opens playstore to install the app.

In chrome, it will be shown when `beforeinstallprompt` event is triggered and on clicking install, i call the `deferredPrompt.prompt()` to show the native app install dialog.

All this works fine, but for the first time, chrome shows the mini-info bar above the banner as shown below. Once we close the mini-infobar, It works as expected next time onward. (Since chrome will not show the mini-infobar for the next 3 months as mentioned in the docs)

[image: Image showing mini-inforbar in chrome]

### Expected Result:

[image: Expected result without the info minibar]

My Next.js code to show the install banner is as below.

```
getInitialState() {
    const { userAgent } = this.props;
    const bDetails = new BrowserDetails(userAgent);

    return {
        deferredPrompt: null,
        showBanner: bDetails.isMobile() && bDetails.isAndroid() && !bDetails.isChrome(),
        isChrome: bDetails.isChrome(),
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { isChrome } = this.state;
    if (isChrome) {
        this.listenForInstallBanner();
    }
}

onClickInstallApp() {
    const { deferredPrompt } = this.state;
    deferredPrompt.prompt();
    deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choice) => {
        if (choice.outcome === 'accepted') {
            this.closeDialog();
        }
    });
}

listenForInstallBanner = () => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            deferredPrompt: e,
            showBanner: true,
        });
    });
};

closeDialog() {
    this.setState({ showBanner: false, deferredPrompt: null });
}

render() {
    const { showBanner, isChrome } = this.state;
    return showBanner && (
        <div className="root">
            <div className="banner-body">
                <div className="icon-container">
                    <img className="icon" src={ffLogo} alt="FareFirst Logo" />
                </div>
                <div className="text-container">
                    <h5 className="title">FareFirst</h5>
                    <p className="desc"> Install the app to enjoy offers and more.</p>
                </div>
                <div className="bt-container">
                    {/* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger */}
                    <button type="button" className="close btn-close" aria-label="Close" onClick={this.closeDialog} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: closeSvg }} />
                    {isChrome && <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary bt-install" onClick={this.onClickInstallApp}>Install</button>}
                    {
                    /* eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger */
                    !isChrome && <a className="btn btn-secondary bt-install" href="https://farefirst.page.link/pwa_install"> Install </a>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <style jsx>{styles}</style>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is there any way to disable the google chrome's mini-infobar or if not then any other alternative?

Comment: Not ideal, but if you remove the service worker it will suppress the mini-infobar. You can still add it to the home screen (noticeable delay now though, but not too bad) and it will install using the manifest.json. Maybe, you could reinstate the service worker depending on if in standalone mode or after app has started.

Comment: Problem here is that if I remove the service worker, I will not get the `beforeinstallprompt` as well.